# ¿Qué es una clase (class) en javascript?

Tags: javascript, poo

- factura1 y factura2 son los objetos instanciados que tendran mis propiedades gracias a los parametros del metodo constructor
- get permite encapsular propiedades para que sean privadas y set para lo contrario
- class en si misma que es?
- **Factura es un objeto o class es un objeto? No entiendo la primera linea.**

```js
class Factura{
  constructor(numero, importe, divisa, nombre){
    this._numero = numero;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._divisa = divisa;
    this._nombre = nombre;
  }
  get total(){
    return this._importe;
  }
}
let factura1 = new Factura(112, 255, 'euro', 'fran');
let factura2 = new Factura(11, 210, 'dolar', 'alvaro');
console.log(factura1._numero);
console.log(factura2._numero);
console.log(factura2.total);
```

Comment: cual es tu pregunta en particular, porque no veo ningun error  el codigo y las preguntas son muy basicas

Comment: Nada soy nuevo en esto solo me estaba confundiendo un poco con Factura, se que es un objeto 'plantilla' digamos, pero console.log me dice que es una funcion. Entonces es funcion y objeto?

Comment: en POO decir un objeto plantilla esta mal, Clases = Plantilla , Objeto es una instancia de la Clase , los metodos son funciones de las clases, es muy comun escuchar estas palabras mezcladas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> class en si misma que es?

Que es una clase? es la forma de definir una colección de objetos permitiendo que estos posean los mismos atributos y metodos.

Así por ejemplo si tienes un **Auto**, sabes que el Auto posee propiedades como color, marca, potencia y posee unos métodos asociados cómo acelerar, frenar, encender motor, apagar motor. **Entonces que es una clase?** es la que permite generar una o más instancias de un objeto. En este caso si deseas "registrar" 2 autos de una misma marca pero con colores distintos (por ejemplo) necesitas generar 2 "instancias" de la clase "Auto".

> Factura es un objeto o class es un objeto? No entiendo la primera
>   linea.

Con lo que expliqué anteriormente pues **Factura** es una **clase**. **Que es una clase?** una colección de objetos (recordemos que es la que permite generar varias instancias). **Cuando Factura es "un objeto"?** cuando realizas una instancia de la clase factura.

Ejemplo: `let factura1 = new Factura(112, 255, 'euro', 'fran');`

Comment: Okok gracias, una cosilla mas, Factura es como un Objeto 'plantilla' que todas las instancias usaran, okay, PERO, a su vez es una funcion no? ya que HACE ALGO, ademas en console.log pone que Factura es function. Se que Function es objeto ya que gracias a sus instancias puedo acceder a sus propiedades(no directamente desde el objeto Factura), entonces, Factura es aparte de un objeto 'plantilla' una funcion????? Gracias Huskie

Comment: plantilla y clases en contexto de POO son lo mismo, la clase tiene caracteristicas  y atributos unicos

Comment: @franciscodwq Pasa que es cómo te decía javascript tiene "clases" como termino relativamente nuevo. Es por ello que cuando haces el console.log muestra function, ya que en javascript todo se maneja a base de funciones lo de las clases es una "adaptación" que se le hizo al lenguaje para que soportara y adaptara correctamente el paradigma de POO

Answer (score 0):

`get` te permite devolver el valor de una propiedad. En tu caso `total` será una propiedad de sólo lectura cuyo valor se puede obtener gracias al método `get` pero no se puede establecer directamente.

`set` permite establecer el valor de una propiedad. Si total tuviese un método `set` permitiría establecer el valor de esta propiedad (`factura1.total = nuevovalor`)

`class` es una palabra reservada para especificar una definición de objetos, una especie de plantilla a usar para crear los obejtos. En esta plantilla se define cómo se crean los objetos de tipo `Factura`, qué propiedades tienen, cuáles son de sólo lectura, etc.

Una vez creada esa "plantilla" puedes crear objetos utilizándola a través de la palabra reservada `new`.

Es decir `Factura` es un tipo de objeto que tiene un comportamiento definido. `factura1` y `factura2` son objetos del tipo `Factura` y por tanto tienen el comportamiento definido en la "plantilla" `Factura`.

Comment: Entonces Factura es la plantilla de todos los que luego podre crear con new, lo que no entiendo es porque si Factura es un objeto, en console.log me dice que es un function? Por cierto muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Otra cosa, entonces constructor y get y set son metodos de QUE OBJETO??? Factura?

Comment: Factura es la definición de un tipo de objeto. La definición de clases no existía hasta la definición del estándar de ECMAScript 6, hasta entonces lo que se definía era una función constructora. Es posible que por eso al hacer un `console.log` de la definición de la clase te indique que es de tipo `function`. `constructor`, `get` y `set` son palabras reservadas que se utilizan para indicar la utilidad de los métodos en la definición de una clase, en concreto: definir el constructor, devolver el valor de una propiedad y establecer el valor de una propiedad respectivamente.

Comment: Ahhh vale gracias, entonces class crea como una plantilla Factura, que en realidad es un objeto/function al que no se puede acceder a el con .notation , solo a traves de sus instancias de objeto no? Mil gracias

Comment: Eso es. `Factura` sirve para crear objetos en base a esa plantilla a través de la palabra reservada `new`. Esos objetos creados a través de `new` son los que tienen propiedades a las que se les puede asignar o recuperar valores.

Comment: Ya ya entendia, pero me confundio pasar de function constructor a class ya que en function constructor sabia que era una funcion, sin embargo no entendia porque podia darles un metodo get y set a una funcion, pero Factura es a su vez funcion, ya que crea una plantilla de facturas y un objeto tipo, vamos es funcion y objeto al mismo tiempo asi es?. Mil gracias Asier te doy mi like =)

Answer (score 0):

class es una palabra reservada la cual te permite crear una clase de tipo Factura  factura1 y factura2 son tus objetos y tienen sus atributos numero, importe,divisa,nombre.

Total es un metodo, el cual te retorna el atributo importe.

factura1 y factura2 son objetos diferentes, ya que cada uno tiene diferentes atributos (numero, importe,divisa,nombre.
)

Las palabras reservadas no pueden ser utilizadas como una variable, funciones, métodos o identificadores de objetos. Las siguientes son reservadas como palabras claves existentes por la especificación ECMAScript.

Cada lenguaje de programación tiene sus palabras reservadas.

[palabras reservadas javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Palabras_Reservadas)

Comment: Entonces Factura no solo es un objeto Prototipo si no una funcion, es ambas no?

Comment: @franciscodwq Factura es una clase. Cuando realizas una instancia de Factura, esta instancia genera un objeto. En javascript te dice que es función porque originalmente javascript trabaja es con funciones. Apenas en 2015 es que se ha empezado a hablar de "clases" en javascript

Answer (score 0):

te explicare con ejemplo mas simple, para entender que es cada una de las cosas:

**Clases**: Class Plantilla, sirven para ver agrupar comportamiento.

**Objetos**: es una instancia de la Clase, tiene comportamientos unico (Esto traera comentarios)

**Atributos y metodos**: son funcionalidades del objeto

Ejemplo Practico:

```js
class Jugador{
  constructor(nombre, numero,  equipo, nacionalidad){
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._numero = numero;
    this._equipo = equipo;
    this._nacionalidad = nacionalidad;

  }

}
let jugador1 = new Jugador("Messi", 10, "Barcelona", 'Argentina');
let jugador2 = new Jugador("Cristiano", 7, 'Real Madrid', 'Portugal');
console.log("El jugador 1 es " + jugador1._nombre );
console.log("El jugador 2 es " + jugador2._nombre );
console.log("Ellos jugaran junto cuando el equipo " + jugador1._equipo + " enfrente al " + jugador2._equipo )
```

> En javascript tambien existe algo llamado prototype realiza lo mismo que una clase solo que es mas confuso